# How to convert a list of polynomials into a list of equations and plug into Contourplot?

Tags: plotting, conversion

Given a list `q` of polynomials (output of GroebnerBasis) in two variables I want to transform the list into a list of equations and plug it into CountourPlot. For example

```
q = {y1^2 + y2^2 - 1, y1 - y2};
ContourPlot[{q[[1]] == 0, q[[2]] == 0}, {y1, -2, 2}, {y2, -2, 2}]
ContourPlot[Thread[Equal[q, 0]], {y1, -2, 2}, {y2, -2, 2}]
```

The second line works but is not suitable (unknown number of equations in general) and the third line produces an empty plot (although

```
    {q[[1]] == 0, q[[2]] == 0} == Thread[Equal[q, 0]]
```

evalutes True). Is there another way to plot level curves of an unknown list of polynomials ?

Comment: In your last command, wrap your first argument in Evaluate.

Comment: @FredSimons has got it.  When in doubt, add an `Evaluate` and see what happens.